# Thread real time synchronisation in C langage

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, real-time, semaphore

I'm learning real-time programming in C, I'm still a beginner.
I have created a simple periodic task that calculates the sum and I am now trying to synchronize two real-time tasks (periodic task) one of the tasks will use a result produced by the other task.

My question is how to synchronize periodic tasks ?? for now I want to do that and then I will try to use the priorities.

My second question is how can i use `pthread_create(&th2, NULL, tache2, "2")` to return int ??

Thank you very much for helping me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t evt;

void* tache1(void *arg){
    int i=0;

    while(i<2){
        printf("La tache %s s'execute\n", (char*) arg);

        sem_post(&evt);
        i++;
    }
}

void* tache2(void *arg){
    int i=0;
    while(i<2){
        sem_wait(&evt);
        printf("La tache %s s'execute enfin\n", (char*) arg);

        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t th1, th2;
    sem_init(&evt, 0,2 );

    pthread_create(&th1, NULL, tache1, "1");
    pthread_create(&th2, NULL, tache2, "2");

    pthread_join(th1, NULL);
    pthread_join(th2, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Firstly Linux or Windows are not real time systems.

Comment: The simplest way to share data between threads is to use global variables. To protect their setting and their use, do some research about *mutexes* and *locks*.

Comment: OKkk i will research and will try again